# How to reduce the react native project size

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a project and when I have released that, the size it is 30MB!
I have edited the gradle file :

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false  to def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false to def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```

but it only has reduced 4MB.
Now I wanna know how can I reduce that At least 15MB. Can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to load the `static assets` such as `images` through the server and cache them in your app

Answer (score 1):

`React Native` project size usually depends on the libraries you use in your project, it is obvious that if you use more external libraries, your app size will also increase. Always try to make components on your own like Headers, Input fields, Cards etc. This approach will also increase your understanding and the size of your app will also be smaller. Only use those libraries which are important like `react-native-maps` to show data on maps etc. Otherwise, try to make things with your own code.